# jasmine - javascript testing closures

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, closures, jasmine

I have the following methods.. I'd like to be able to mock something up so I can test whether or not pete() has been called. Not sure how to do this when im using closures. Any ideas ?

```
bla = (function(){
     var a = 0;
     jim = function(){
         if(a==1){
             pete();
         }
     },
     pete = function(){
         return 1;
     }

     var publicInterface = {
         "publicjim": jim
     }
     return publicInterface;
})();
```

Comment: fixed my example to use the correct syntax .. sorry for the inital typo.

Comment: (I feel like a schmo - I just replied on some SO scraping site)

Do you really want to test that pete was called when you call jim? Or do you want to test that when you call jim, that something happens (that pete triggers)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your self-executing anonymous function, you're using object propertys.

`jim` and `pete` need to be local variables in order to "hide" them via closure.

```
var bla = (function(){
    var a = 1;
    var jim = function() {
      if (a == 1) {
         pete();
      }
    };
    var pete = function() {
        return 1;
    };

    return {
       "publicjim": jim
    };  
})();
```

Comment: you made a valid point I  had been accidentally using the ":" property syntax in my sanitized example. I've updated my example code to clarify. In my real code I am using the "=" I am still learning js so at times my syntax is a bit shaky.  My problem remains - how might I within unit tests  using Jasmine might I asertain that pete(); has been called or is it not possible ?